# Why does this ContourPlot3D give a faulty plot?

Tags: plotting

Why in Wolfram Development Platform does this:

```
ContourPlot3D[Abs[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 -1]==0.2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},PlotPoints->8]
```

give a faulty plot:

[image]

and how can I remedy, without changing the plotted expression?

Note: Workarounding by increasing PlotPoints gives a correct plot when it succeed

[image]

but often fails with a server issues error.

PS Do not mistake this for a duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97845/why-is-this-computation-failing .

Comment: Define faulty, in other words: what are you expecting here that you're not getting?

Comment: 1) What are you trying to achieve by asking for such low `PlotPoint` count? 2) The result you obtain is the same that I get on a desktop MMA, so I don't think it's faulty. 3) What is the difference between this question and your previous one which you say is not a duplicate?

Comment: "What are you trying to achieve by asking for such low PlotPoint count?" As I said, increased PlotPoints causes server fail.

Comment: @rcollyer Example of expected added. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is artifacts from constructing the surface on a grid. To visualize this process, we can adapt the code from [this example](http://wolfram.com/xid/0d6eyml5tk-husmjq):

```
Clear[showPts];
SetAttributes[showPts, HoldAll];
showPts[e : (h_)[f_, its__, opts : OptionsPattern[]]] := 
Block[{pts, vars},
  vars = {its}[[All, 1]];
  pts = Reap[h[f, its, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[vars], opts]][[-1, 1]];
  Show[e, If[Length@{its} == 3, ListPointPlot3D, ListPlot][pts]]
]
```

This is far easier to see in 2D. So, first, let us look at what happens with `ContourPlot` with increasing `PlotPoints`:

```
{showPts@ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 0],
 showPts@ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 0]}
```

[image]

As you can see, the algorithm used requires points on either side of contour for a line to be drawn. `MaxRecursion` can speed up this up by allowing sub-divisions between the initial `PlotPoints` to be used, too:

```
{showPts@ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 1],
 showPts@ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotPoints -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 1]}
```

[image]

To see this in 3D, we need to carefully adjust the view

```
showPts@ContourPlot3D[Abs[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1] == 0.2, 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 8]
```

[image]

and we see that despite the large number of points near some of the surface, no points are used in the gap. Increasing the `MaxRecursion` does not help. Unfortunately, `ContourPlot3D` does not accept the region form, as it helps redistribute the points, e.g.

```
{showPts@ContourPlot[
   x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 2], 
   PlotPoints -> 2, MaxRecursion -> 0],
 showPts@ContourPlot[
   x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y} \[Element] Disk[{0, 0}, 2], 
   PlotPoints -> 3, MaxRecursion -> 0]}
```

[image]

Comment: I forget. Is `ContourPlot3D[]` using marching cubes, or marching tetrahedra?

Comment: @J.M. I honestly don't know. But, based on how the recursion progresses, it appears to be cubes. But, that's just a guess.