# Why does this output fail to respond to mouse drags to rotate the object?

Tags: plotting

Why does the output of

```
Clear[showPts];
SetAttributes[showPts, HoldAll];
showPts[e : (h_)[f_, its__, opts : OptionsPattern[]]] := 
Block[{pts, vars},
  vars = {its}[[All, 1]];
  pts = Reap[h[f, its, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[vars], opts]][[-1, 1]];
  Show[e, If[Length@{its} == 3, ListPointPlot3D, ListPlot][pts]]
]

showPts@ContourPlot3D[Abs[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1] == 0.2, 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 4]
```

being

[image]

fail to respond to mouse drags to rotate the object?

This problem does not affect

```
ContourPlot3D[Abs[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 1] == 0.2, 
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 4]
```

EDIT: This is using Wolfram Cloud. $Version says "11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)".

EDIT: Kuba, in view of [the stated opposition to the Wolfram cloud tag being added to a question not determined to be specific to the Wolfram cloud](https://archive.is/Agt79), I have removed the wolfram-cloud tag you added. If you're certain this question is specific to the Wolfram cloud, please feel free to re-add the tag provided you cite that evidence. Thanks.

Comment: What version are you using? It works fine with v10.4.1 and v11.0 on my Mac. Perhaps you need to start with a fresh kernel.

Comment: @Bob, it seems the OP is using the free WDP for his plots. It does seem to be a bit... restricted.

Comment: Agreed, nice indeed. Credit to rcollyer http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97880/why-does-this-contourplot3d-give-a-faulty-plot . Now I wish I understood how it worked! :-)

Comment: @Bob $Version says "11.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)". Access is via Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I don't understand, I know it works on desktop MMA and it does not on cloud. You only know it does not on cloud. Why have you deleted the tag then?

Comment: @Kuba I don't know it is specific to WC. If you do, then as I suggested please state the evidence when you (re)add the tag... cos I'd prefer not to see interference from the tag zealots https://archive.is/Agt79  .